# Laravel 9.48.0 + PHP 8.1.6 in VSCode shows syntax error

Tags: visual-studio-code, composer-php, laravel-9, php-8.1

i have win10
in cmd.exe with composer create project:
composer create-project laravel/laravel firstproject
or(laravel new firstproject)

then:
php artisan serve

[image]

but in vscode i have some syntax error in vendor folder

[image]

list of errors:

Syntax error:unexpected token 'string' php(php2014)
Syntax error:unexpected token 'array' php(php2014)
...

in AppData\Roaming\Code\User\setting.json
"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.6"

how can i fix errors?

Comment: What kind of error are you facing? How is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: this project created via composer in cmd.exe:
project laravel/laravel firstproject 

list of errors:

Syntax error:unexpected token 'string' php(php2014) 

Syntax error:unexpected token 'array' php(php2014)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share how the problem is related to Composer. Wouldn't it also occur if the project was created any other way?

Comment: i added all clarification to my question